# In 2022, Is It Still Possible to Use Google Sheets API with a Service Account?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, service-accounts

The Google documentation on their Nodejs Quickstart is not great and it only shows an example of authenticating with an OAuth credential. I have a working, functional Discord bot that writes to my personal Google Sheet. However, because it's unverified by Google, my refresh token expires every 7 days and my bot will just stop working without warning until I manually go back in and give the user consent again. This is a pain, obviously.

From what I understand, a Service Account wouldn't have this issue, however, I've been unable to find a working example of the authorize function when using a Service Account JSON key. For the OAuth key, I have this:

```
/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.GoogleAuth(client_id, client_secret);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    return callback(oAuth2Client, arguments[2], arguments[3]);
  });
}
```

The extra "arguments" parameters are just values I'm passing to the callback. Does anyone have any working examples of using the current API with a Service Account in Node? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least with the version 3.1.15 of `google-spreadsheet` that I used to work with Google Spreadsheet API I did this in order to connect using a service account (the example will be in typescript):

```js
import { GoogleSpreadsheet } from 'google-spreadsheet';

async function getDocument(sheetId: string): Promise<GoogleSpreadsheet> {
  const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(sheetId);

  await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
    client_email: serviceEmail,
    private_key: servicePrivateKey.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
  })
  // now we can use `doc`
  return doc;
}
```

Some usages:

```js
    const doc = await getSpreadsheet(documentId);
    await doc.loadInfo();
    const sheet = doc.sheetsByTitle[sheetName];
    const totalRowCount = sheet.rowCount;
    ...
    await sheet.loadCells({
        startRowIndex: 1,
        endRowIndex: 100,
        startColumnIndex: 0,
        endColumnIndex: 10
    });
    const cell = sheet.getCell(rowIndex, columnIndex);
```

Comment: Okay, excuse my ignorance, but in this example we can then get data from "doc", right? Currently, I'm doing this:


 const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
    sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadsheetId: id,
        range: range,
    }, async (err, res) => {
        if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        const rows = res.data.values;
  // do stuff
   });


In your example, do we not have to re-authenticate with every call like with oauth?

Comment: Nope, let me add some usage lines in the answer

Comment: great, thank you! I just realized this is a separate project, wrapping Google's API. I hadn't seen this before (and have only been using the straight Google library from their documentation). This looks much easier to use honestly, so I'm going to attempt a rewrite using this. Thanks for the help! 

For those wondering, the library is at: https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet